# Hosmer–Lemeshow test - Best Model

Tags: regression, goodness-of-fit, regression-strategies

I have 3 different models and I do the Hosmer–Lemeshow test. I have a p-value and a Chi2 value. How can I know which model fits the best my data?

Khi-2 || Pr > Khi-2

12.04 || 0.19

7.47 || 0.71

4.34 || 0.46

Is it the one with the biggest p-value?

Answer (score 1):

The Hosmer-Lemeshow test has been replaced by a number of more powerful methods that have been described elsewhere on this site.  Use the Search bar to find them.

Model selection is often discouraged, and using goodness-of-fit statistics to select models is especially discouraged.  Better would be to carefully specify a model that is as flexible as your sample size will support, fit the model, and stop.

Comment: but could we say that the best model here is the one with  the biggest p-value?

Comment: Not in the least.  Don't use a goodness-of-fit statistic to select a model.  Use an accepted optimality criterion, and even there it was intended to be used only when selecting from among 2-3 **pre-specified** models.   In general, model selection is not a great idea.  Model specification is.